Bevel modifier interpolating named attributes
I've been playing around with named attributes and have run into an issue with the way the bevel modifier works. The problem I'm having is that the bevel modifier is interpolating everything including all my named attributes... Normally, this would be fine, unfortunately, I have a project that would be greatly simplified by being able to assign immutable IDs to things.
Here's a toy example demonstrating what I mean, ideally only two vertices should have a value of "1000" and all others should remain at "0", but when the bevel modifier adds new vertices, it interpolates the named attributes and they end up with a value of "914" instead of (in this particular case) the desired value of "0"

Is there a way to have named attributes that are NOT interpolated by the bevel modifier?
(I'm not adverse to an API-only solution if that's what it takes)

Not sure you can prevent that.
But you can "fix" that, by creating an additional geometry nodes to place after the bevel, setting to 0 the values that are < 999.99
